# Отсортировать список по максимальным значениям и без дубликатов в названии в Postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Допустим есть такая таблица, помогите написать запрос, выбрать 5 записей с максимальными значениями поля price отсортированными по убыванию но без повторяющихся имен;

name | price

A    | 300

B    | 3567

C    | 456

D    | 1000

A    | 5000

B    | 6700

C    | 5999

D    | 5555

B    | 6770

C    | 6003

A    | 4567

D    | 999

F    | 2356

G    | 222

Результат должен быть таким:

name | price

B    | 6670

C    | 6003

D    | 5555

A    | 5000

F    | 2356

Answer (score 0):

Запрос

```
select distinct(name),max(price) from tablename
group by 1
order by 2
limit 5
```

Отсортирует по 2 столбцу